# Package error in Python

Tags: python, chat, kivy

I'm get this error when I try to run Chat.
https://github.com/Basse-s/kb/tree/master/4_Chat

```
 [WARNING           ] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 14)
    [WARNING           ] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
    [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/Basse/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-19_0.txt
    [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
    [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
    [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
    [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_gif, img_pil (img_pygame, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
    pygame - ImportError: No module named pygame
      File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
        fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
      File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 8, in <module>
        import pygame

    [CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.`enter code here`
```

I have downloaded Kivy and Twisted. I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: Have you installed all of the Kivy's dependencies? Read this if you have any installation problems: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation

Comment: sebastians-mbp:~ Basse$ python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew \
> kivy.deps.gstreamer --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pygments in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/rp/5jf_ylkj3m5g6d4hlcdv4h5h0000gn/T/pip-build-PORSNV/pypiwin32/setup.py", line 83, in <module>
        import _winreg
    ImportError: No module named _winreg
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/rp/5jf_ylkj3m5g6d4hlcdv4h5h0000gn/T/pip-build-PORSNV/pypiwin32/

Comment: I get this error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/rp/5jf_ylkj3m5g6d4hlcdv4h5h0000gn/T/pip-build-PORSNV/pypiwin32/

Comment: That guide was for Windows, it appears you have a Mac

Comment: @Sebastian, Please put problem details into the question, formatted properly.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, it's easiest to use the [Kivy.app package](https://kivy.org/downloads/1.9.1/Kivy-1.9.1-osx-python2.7z). This app already contains all of the dependencies so you won't have this issue. It also uses SDL2 instead of pygame (SDL1).

From [User Guide - Installation on OS X](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html):

> 1. Download the latest version from http://kivy.org/#download Kivy2.7z is using using Python 2 (System Python), Kivy3.7z (Python 3)
> 2. Extract it using an archive program like Keka.
> 3. Copy the Kivy2.app or Kivy3.app as Kivy.app to /Applications. Paste the following line in the terminal:
>
>    `$ sudo mv Kivy2.app /Applications/Kivy.app`
> 4. Create a symlink named kivy to easily launch apps with kivy venv:
>
>    `$ ln -s /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/script /usr/local/bin/kivy`
> 5. Examples and all the normal kivy tools are present in the Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because you haven't got all dependencies. Kivy uses `pygame` and you don't have that installed. Since you haven't provided any information about your Python version or OS (which you should have, even though it can be seen in the log), read the installation page on the Kivy website. If you have OS X, they provide a Kivy file with all dependencies. The link to the website is [here](https://kivy.org/#download). There are also complete instructions about what you should do once you have the file in case that causes you problems. If that still hasn't fixed your problem, install `pygame` manually. Link with instructions [here](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted).

Answer (score -1):

It appears you are missing the `pygame` module

To install it, Download the installer from here, and follow the [instructions](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) :

[pygame Download](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)